# angularJS method POST 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to save data in database, Im using angular and I used a file php to access to database, the problem is : POST http://127.0.0.1:9090/insert_indispo.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)..
please how to resolve this problem !......

here my function post:

```js
    function ValideConge(id,debut,fin) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: window.location.href + 'insert_indispo.php',
                data: {id,debut,fin},
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).then(function (success){
                deferred.resolve("ok!");
                console.log("ok c!");
            },function (error){
                deferred.resolve(false);
                console.log("ok n!");
            });
            return deferred.promise;

        }
```

and here my file insert_indispo.php

```js
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $id = $request->id;
    $debut = $request->debut;
    $fin = $request->fin;


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "plann";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO indisp (id,id_form,date_debut,date_fin)
VALUES ('', $id, $debut , $fin)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "ajouté avec succé !";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This means that the *server* doesn't allow the POST method, for whatever reason. You'll need to look under the hood there.

Comment: I tried to make those instructions but the problem still :                                   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type');

Comment: The problem most likely has something to do with the server configuration rather than the PHP program.